# Uncaught Error: You did not set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key. all things are well config

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

.env file

```
STRIPE_KEY = pk_test_123...
STRIPE_SECRET = sk_test_123...
```

Stripe Form Code

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var $form = $(".stripe-payment");
        $('form.stripe-payment').bind('submit', function (e) {
            var $form = $(".stripe-payment"),
                inputVal = ['input[type=email]', 'input[type=password]',
                    'input[type=text]', 'input[type=file]',
                    'textarea'
                ].join(', '),
                $inputs = $form.find('.required').find(inputVal),
                $errorStatus = $form.find('div.error'),
                valid = true;
            $errorStatus.addClass('hide');

            $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
            $inputs.each(function (i, el) {
                var $input = $(el);
                if ($input.val() === '') {
                    $input.parent().addClass('has-error');
                    $errorStatus.removeClass('hide');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                Stripe.setPublishableKey($form.data('stripe-publishable-key'));
                Stripe.createToken({
                    number: $('.card-num').val(),
                    cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
                    exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
                    exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
                }, stripeRes);
            }

        });

        function stripeRes(status, response) {
            if (response.error) {
                $('.error')
                    .removeClass('hide')
                    .find('.alert')
                    .text(response.error.message);
            } else {
                var token = response['id'];
                $form.find('input[type=text]').empty();
                $form.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
                $form.get(0).submit();
            }
        }

    });

</script>
```

```html
<form role="form" action="{{ route('make-payment') }}" method="post" class="stripe-payment"
                            data-cc-on-file="false" data-stripe-publishable-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
                            id="stripe-payment">
                            @csrf

                            <div class='form-row row'>
                                <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required'>
                                    <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label> <input class='form-control'
                                        size='4' type='text'>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class='form-row row'>
                                <div class='col-xs-12 form-group card required'>
                                    <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label> <input autocomplete='off'
                                        class='form-control card-num' size='20' type='text'>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class='form-row row'>
                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group cvc required'>
                                    <label class='control-label'>CVC</label>
                                    <input autocomplete='off' class='form-control card-cvc' placeholder='e.g 595'
                                        size='4' type='text'>
                                </div>
                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                                    <label class='control-label'>Expiration Month</label> <input
                                        class='form-control card-expiry-month' placeholder='MM' size='2' type='text'>
                                </div>
                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                                    <label class='control-label'>Expiration Year</label> <input
                                        class='form-control card-expiry-year' placeholder='YYYY' size='4' type='text'>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class='form-row row'>
                                <div class='col-md-12 hide error form-group'>
                                    <div class='alert-danger alert'>Fix the errors before you begin.</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Pay</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Error when submit the form

> (index):3 Uncaught Error: You did not set a valid publishable key.
> Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key. For more
> info, see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js
> at Function.b.validateKey ((index):3)
> at Function.b.create ((index):2)
> at Function.c.createToken ((index):2)
> at HTMLFormElement. ((index):103)
> at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
> at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0):

[Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#setup) should be [initialized](https://stripe.com/docs/js/initializing) with your publishable key:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_123');
```

Additionally, you should not be collecting card details in your own form inputs, as it has [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) implications. Instead, you should use [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) to securely collect this. Stripe's [payment guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-collect-card-details) details how to implement this.